# Creating a custom button shape with inverted corner WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, templates, button

I am trying to create a custom button in WPF in this shape:

[image]

But am struggling on the inverted CornerRadius in the bottom right. I have seen various examples of combining Rectangle and Ellipse shapes, or by using a custom path, however I haven't seen any examples of how to then turn that into a button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turning your design into a button is simple, you make it the Content of your Button. Using the [CombinedGeometry Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.combinedgeometry), sky's the limit to what you can make (see [How to: Create a Combined Geometry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/graphics-multimedia/how-to-create-a-combined-geometry)). Here's an implementation of your design using CombinedGeometry:

```
<Button>
    <Grid>
        <Path Fill="White"
                Width="160"
                Height="160">
            <Path.Data>

                <CombinedGeometry GeometryCombineMode="Union">
                    <CombinedGeometry.Geometry1>
                        <CombinedGeometry GeometryCombineMode="Exclude">
                            <CombinedGeometry.Geometry1>
                                <CombinedGeometry GeometryCombineMode="Exclude">
                                    <CombinedGeometry.Geometry1>
                                        <RectangleGeometry Rect="80,0,80,160" />
                                    </CombinedGeometry.Geometry1>
                                    <CombinedGeometry.Geometry2>
                                        <EllipseGeometry RadiusX="40"
                                                            RadiusY="40"
                                                            Center="120,160" />
                                    </CombinedGeometry.Geometry2>
                                </CombinedGeometry>
                            </CombinedGeometry.Geometry1>
                            <CombinedGeometry.Geometry2>
                                <RectangleGeometry Rect="0,120,120,40" />
                            </CombinedGeometry.Geometry2>
                        </CombinedGeometry>
                    </CombinedGeometry.Geometry1>

                    <CombinedGeometry.Geometry2>
                        <CombinedGeometry GeometryCombineMode="Union">
                            <CombinedGeometry.Geometry1>
                                <CombinedGeometry GeometryCombineMode="Union">
                                    <CombinedGeometry.Geometry1>
                                        <RectangleGeometry Rect="0,0,80,80" />
                                    </CombinedGeometry.Geometry1>
                                    <CombinedGeometry.Geometry2>
                                        <EllipseGeometry RadiusX="40"
                                                            RadiusY="40"
                                                            Center="40,80" />
                                    </CombinedGeometry.Geometry2>
                                </CombinedGeometry>
                            </CombinedGeometry.Geometry1>
                            <CombinedGeometry.Geometry2>
                                <RectangleGeometry Rect="40,0,40,120" />
                            </CombinedGeometry.Geometry2>
                        </CombinedGeometry>
                    </CombinedGeometry.Geometry2>
                </CombinedGeometry>

            </Path.Data>
        </Path>

        <TextBlock Text="Custom Button"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    Foreground="Black" />
    </Grid>
</Button>
```

This could be improved by using less geometry but it gives you a template to work with.

Comment: How would I put this within a custom template to make it easier to implement on multiple buttons?

Comment: @J4ns323 I'd make this a UserControl.

Comment: @J4ns323 please consider accepting this answer if it has answered your question.